# html2Canvas image cut sometime

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

I have below code

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    const totPage = document.getElementsByClassName('print');
    for (let index = 1; index < totPage.length;) {
        const input = totPage[index] 
        let orn = input.getAttribute('orientation');
        let canvas = await html2canvas(input,{
            windowWidth: input.scrollWidth,
            windowHeight: input.scrollHeight
        });//.then((canvas) => {
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        console.log(imgData)
       
        index++

    }
```

it generates pdf with image cut off. but strangely when I open console on browser and then try it generates images perfectly, and after then even I closed the console the images are generating correctly. its strange but cannot figure out why this is happening

Comment: It's a bit difficult to fathom what you mean here. Could you put up a working snippet so we can try it for ourselves - there's missing info e.g. what html you are trying to print, is everything definitely loaded before writing to the canvas etc.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this:
https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1438#issuecomment-739244530

That is a comment in this post:
[HTML2Canvas does not render full div, only what is visible on screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213275/html2canvas-does-not-render-full-div-only-what-is-visible-on-screen)